# Using Modernizer.js to redirect if page doesn't support drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have successfully configured modernizer.js to tell if a page can support drag and drop or not.  Originally I configured it so that if it was supported to show one div and if not to show the other which worked well until I discovered that two of the js scripts running on this page didn't play nicely with each other.

At this point I decided that the best thing to do is just redirect the user to another page if their browser doesn't support drag and drop.

The problem that I have is that my javascript isn't all that great yet (I'm a works in progress) and although I have managed to configure it to redirect as the else part of an if/else statement I would like it to just redirect using the if without the else (if you know what I mean?).

This what I currently have...

```
window.onload = function() {
   if (window.FileReader && Modernizr.draganddrop){
      //code left from when it was showing hidden divs
      document.getElementById('yes').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('page_blurb').style.display = 'block';
   }else{
      window.location = "http://www.dentaldigs.co.uk/image_upload_non5.php"

   }
};
```

This is what I want to do...

```
window.onload = function() {
   if (window.FileReader && Modernizr.draganddrop not true){
      window.location = "http://www.dentaldigs.co.uk/image_upload_non5.php"   
   }
};
```

I hope that makes sense?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about

```
if(!(window.FileReader && Modernizr.draganddrop))
```

as condition?